# Error while generating NodeJs server code in swagger

Tags: node.js, swagger-3.0

While trying to generate `nodejs` server I am getting the below errors.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Internal Server Error
    at index.js:1
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:62)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:296)
    at Generator.e.(/swagger/anonymous function) [as next] (https://abcdef.com/swagger/dist/swagger-editor-standalone-preset.js:1:104227)
    at step (asyncToGenerator.js:17)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:28

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Is there any solution to solve this errors?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What tool do you use to generate the code? Can you also post your Swagger definition file (JSON/YAML)?

Comment: Swagger Codegen is the tool I am using.Sorry to say this but I am not allowed to share Swagger defination file.

Comment: @NamaniSupriya:  Unless we see the code, it is not possible to solve the issue. "500 internal server" means there is some problem in your server code.

Comment: Just to clarify - is this error produced **by** the generated Node.js server when you run it? It does not seem to be an error from the Swagger Codegen itself.

Comment: @Helen The error is while generating the Node.js server.There is no problem with Swagger Codegen.

Comment: What do you mean by "**while generating** the Node.js server"? What steps/commands exactly did you perform that led to this error? E.g. is this error from `npm start` or similar? (The more details you provide, the easier it is for others to understand the issue and suggest solutions.)